# Rails country-state_select gem javascript not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

After installing country_state_select gem, it successfully loaded the countries but the first country I selected loaded the corresponding states but after selecting another country its corresponding states would not load but rather the state belonging to the last country I selected. I have tried to shut down the sever several times to reset it but would still do same.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@office_item) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if 
  f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

<div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.file_field :pictures, multiple:true %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.association :category, label_method: :title, value_method: :id, 
      include_blank: false, prompt: "Select Category" %>
  <%= f.input :address %>
  <%= f.input :country, collection: CountryStateSelect.countries_collection  
      %>
  <%= f.input :state, CountryStateSelect.state_options(label: "State / 
      Province", form: f, field_names: { :country => :country, :state => 
      :state  } ) %>
  <%= f.input :city, CountryStateSelect.city_options(label: "City ", 
      form: f, field_names: {  :state => :state, :city => :city } ) %>

  <%= f.input :pricing, label: "Price" %>
  <%= f.input :terms, label: "Terms and Conditions" %>
  <%= f.input :is_active, label: "Publish" %>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
</div>
 <% end %>




<script>
   $(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
   return CountryStateSelect({
   country_id: "country",
   state_id: "state"
   city_id: "city"
   });
   });
</script>
```

My expectations are that each country selected will load its corresponding state and city respectively

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.Here is the error i found on the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on  city_id: "city"  in the console. I added a coma after it and the errors disappeared. However, the selections of the corresponding state and city to a selected country does not work.

Comment: Do you get any new errors when you try to select a different country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This gem documentation is a bit outdated, so as you're using Rails 5, first `script` line should be

   ```
   $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
   ```

   or simply

   ```
   $(function() {
   ```
2. Then reload the page and look at the browser's console. If you'll see `CountryStateSelect is not defined` error, you should add gem's javascript asset to your `application.js` file

   ```rb
   //= require country_state_select
   ```
3. You should also ensure you're using [right ids](https://github.com/arvindvyas/Country-State-Select#required-javascript) of `<select>` elements
4. This gem uses POST JSON requests on changing `<select>` values, so if you'll get `422 Unprocessable Entity` with `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.` you can disable this verification by adding to your `ApplicationController` class

   ```rb
   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
   end
   ```

Comment: @Geni if my answer is really helpful please vote it up also